# Load multiple application property files in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have following property files.

- application.properties
- application-dev.properties
- application-dev-us1.properties
- application-dev-eu1.properties

I want to have common dev properties in the dev file and region specific properties in us1 and eu1 files.

I can load default and specific file properties by providing SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE environment variable. But how can I make spring pick up three files, default, dev and dev-us1 ?

Comment: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE accepts *multiple* (comma separated) profiles. This seems also a suited use case for [Profile Groups](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles.groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by injecting the env variables: `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,dev-eu1`
The default profile is picked up by default among the others

Comment: Ok, is there no way where Spring can auto resolve list of required files?

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would spring know what files do you want to load?

Comment: The way, it auto picks up default and dev if Spring-profile = dev, was checking if providing dev-eu1 will let Spring to pick entire chain of default, dev and dev-eu1. I'll spend some more time to check the feasibility, if not will go wit this approach for now.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Active Profiles is plural you can provide a list of profiles. Either as an environment variable like in the other answer or as an annotation:

```
@Profile({"dev", "dev-us1"})
```

The `application.properties` file (= default profile) will be loaded in any case.